# Error message while compiling a program

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I’m a newbie to C++ and Linux. There is this code I’m playing with that requires me to install the HElib (Homomorphic encryption library and other libraries - GMP, NTL) which I did. I want to compile the code (`main.cpp`) that has a header file (`FHE.h`) in HElib. My problem is how can I link `FHE.h` (in `HElib` folder) and `main.cpp` (in another folder) together so that I can compile them. I have tried some commands

```
g++ -I/Home/HElib/src/FHE.h main.cpp -o main
```

Error message

```
main.cpp:1:17: fatal error: FHE.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Another command line

```
g++ -I/Home/HElib/Src/FHE.h -I/Home/SimpleFHESum-master/SimpleFHESum-master/main.cpp -o main]
```

Error Message

```
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

What's wrong and how can I fix this?

Comment: You should check docs of g++ , by `g++  help`, you should do compile with your input file `g++ hello.cpp -o hello`

Comment: Read [3.15 Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html)
in [the manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)

Answer (score 1):

The `-I` flag adds the following directory to the include path of the compiler. This enables you to write e.g. `#include "FHE.h"` even though that file is not located in the same folder as the source file you're trying to compile.

Have you tried just removing the 'FHE.h' part from your -I directive?

`g++ -I/Home/HElib/src ...`